# Regex: Filter string

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010

for other processes I want to split the following line into objects.
The Line is from our Exchange Incomming SMTP Logfile.

```
2014-05-23T08:38:58.869Z,Exchangeserver\External Relay,08D1437A9AEFF27B,5,192.168.100.211:25,192.168.100.211:46964,<,MAIL FROM: <prvs=0220d28471=user@domain.eu>
```

Is it possible to do this with regular expressions?

Desired Output:

```
Time: 08:38:58
Connector: Exchangeserver\External Relay
ExchangeID:08D1437A9AEFF27B
MailFrom:user@domain.eu
```

I´m sorry, but regular expressions are to heavy for my brain..
:(

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need regex for email addres. You can split columns with, well, `-split` :)

```
$arr = @("2014-05-23T08:38:58.869Z,Exchangeserver\External Relay,08D1437A9AEFF27B,5,192.168.100.211:25,192.168.100.211:46964,<,MAIL FROM: <prvs=0220d28471=user@domain.eu> " -split ",")

$ht = [ordered]@{}
$ht["Time"] = $arr[0]
$ht["Connector"] = $arr[1]
$ht["ExchangeID"] = $arr[2]
$ht["MailFrom"] = $($arr[7] -match "([^=@]+@[^>]+)" | Out-Null; $matches[1])

$ht
```

You can then format the results from hashtable to get your desired output.

Comment: Ok.. i will use -split in further tasks! But Exchange 2010 is not compatible with PowerShell V3, so that [ordered] is not available. Don´t know if it is necessary, but the second line (datetime) is not working on our 2008R2 Server. On Windows 8.0 it works, but the Output is:  Name                           Value                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                      
Time                           12:00:00

Comment: @Daniel4711 Someone edited my answer, I didn't cast Time. If you want to extract time, find appropriate formatting string, or just use regex. As of [ordered]: it's not necessary. Hash tables don't guarantee to preserver order of items, but it's not a problem here, you'll probably be referencing the values explicitly by key, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
$line = 
'2014-05-23T08:38:58.869Z,Exchangeserver\External Relay,08D1437A9AEFF27B,5,192.168.100.211:25,192.168.100.211:46964,<,MAIL FROM: <prvs=0220d28471=user@domain.eu>'

$regex = '^[0-9-]+T([0-9:]+).+?,(.+?),(.+?),.+?MAIL FROM: <.*?(\w+@\w+?\.\w+)>'

$line | 
 New-PSObjectFromMatches -pattern $regex -Property $null,Time,Connector,ExchangeID,MailFrom |
 format-list


Time       : 08:38:58
Connector  : Exchangeserver\External Relay
ExchangeID : 08D1437A9AEFF27B
MailFrom   : user@domain.eu
```

You can get that New-PSObjectFromMatches function here:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-PSObjectFromMatches-87d8ce87

Comment: +1 Great function! One of those codeblocks you always recreate when you need them, but never remember to save. Finally got it saved :D

Comment: Thanks (try the -debug)!

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, but modifying the $Regex is hard stuff. -Split is not so powerful, but easy to use!